# SVG images shown blacked out in UWP application

Tags: xaml, svg, uwp, windows-10-universal

me and my team are trying to put some .svg icons in our UWP win10 application (target and min version are Windows 10 Fall Creators update).

In my resource file I defined my SvgImageSource as following:

```
<SvgImageSource x:Key="PencilIcon" UriSource="Images/DeviceMenu/Icon_EditMode_grey.svg" />
```

And I then proceed to use this image source in my component:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource PencilIcon}" />
```

I tried few different svgs and they all render with the right shape, but are all black (first one is the pencil):

[image]

The original svg looks like this:

[image]

Here is the source code of the [SVG](http://svgshare.com/i/470.svg)

I tried adjusting Stretch, Width, Height and so on but I just can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem of Adobe Illustrator, try playing with its SVG export settings.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test Adobe Illustrator, since our designer is on the other side of the world. However I managed to fix the issue but importing/exporting images to InkScape

Answer (score 5):

UWP has no clue what css styles are.
In my case there was this:

```
<style
     type="text/css"
     id="style2">
    .st0{fill:#996459;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st2{fill:#B4B6BC;}
    .st3{fill:#5C546A;}
    .st4{fill:#868491;}
    .st5{fill:#0F4499;}
</style>
```

To fix this for UWP, find every class="..." and manually apply the style.

Answer (score 2):

If illustrator 
Use Styling: "Presentation Attributes"[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use illustrator then try to change styling. It should be something like Style Attributes.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

UWP just partially supports SVG Ver 1.1 specification (see [SVG Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt790715(v%3Dvs.85).aspx))

And it doesn't support css-like styles.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCngt.png)

You can play with export settings of Adobe Illustrator for export image : [AI export Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChaiG.jpg)

Or fix it manually: [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp2tx.png)

Or with my tool:

- Visual Studio extension at  [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YevhenCherkes.svgforuwpextension).
- Desktop version at [Github releases](https://github.com/ycherkes/SVG-for-UWP/releases)

This tool just inlines css styles directly to the svg elements.